# Python: threads can only be started once

Tags: python, multithreading

I want to do threading in python. I have 100 words and want to put them in 6 different links. If one of the links is ready, I want that the link can get the new word. This while the other threads have still the first word in work. My complete program should be allowed to do more code first when the 100 keywords are done. I have the following code:

```
threads = []

def getresults(seed):
    for link in links:
        t = threading.Thread(target=getLinkResult, args = (suggestengine, seed))
        threads.append(t)
    for thread in threads:
        thread.start()

for seed in tqdm:
    getresults(seed + a)
    getresults(seed + b)

for thread in threads:
    thread.join()

#code that should happen after
```

I get an error at the moment:
    threads can only be started once

Comment: Please post your error

Comment: @Kasramvd With this code I get the error "threads can only be started once" how can I change my code so that everything works?

Comment: @GilbertAllen RuntimeError: threads can only be started once

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You are calling `getresults` twice, and both times, they reference the same global `threads` list. This means, that when you call `getresults` for the first time, threads are started.

When you call them for the second time, the previous threads that are already running, have the `.start()` method invoked again.

You should start threads in the `getresults` as local threads, and then append them to the global `threads` list.

Although you can do the following:

```
for thread in threads:
    if not thread.is_alive():
        thread.start()
```

it does not solve the problem as one or more threads might've already ended and therefore be started again, and would therefore cause the same error.

Comment: If I change my code so that thread.join for every thread is after get results I get the same error

Comment: @Sonius try my suggestion, see if it works. It probably should.

Comment: I am trying it again. But now I get the massage: 'list' object has no attribute 'is_alive'

Comment: @Sonius Should be `thread.is_alive` not `threads`. My mistake, it has been corrected.

Answer (score 5):

You should start only new threads in your getresults

```
threads = []

def getresults(seed):
  local_threads = []
  for link in links:
      t = threading.Thread(target=getLinkResult, args = (suggestengine, seed))
      local_threads.append(t)
      threads.append(t)
  for thread in local_threads:
      thread.start()

for seed in tqdm:
  getresults(seed + a)
  getresults(seed + b)

for thread in threads:
        thread.join()
```

Comment: this I had first. But then I just can do 1 word in 5 threads. If all 5 threads are ready I can do the next word. But with the solution of Games Brainic the third word could be in thread 1 while thread 2 still works on word 1 :)

Answer (score 3):

Fastest way, but not the brightest (general problem):

```
from tkinter import *
import threading, time

def execute_script():
    def sub_execute():
        print("Wait 5 seconds")
        time.sleep(5)
        print("5 seconds passed by")
    threading.Thread(target=sub_execute).start()

root = Tk()
button_1 = Button(master=root, text="Execute Script", command=execute_script)
button_1.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I like how you added a GUI to the answer just for the show.

Answer (score 0):

The error is explicit. You start your threads twice, while you shouldn't.

```
getresults(seed + a)
getresults(seed + b)
```

When you sequence these calls you start twice the loop of threads. To properly do what you want to do, you to make a [thread pool and a task queue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_pool). Basically, you need a second list of words to process and a mutex. Each thread will lock the mutex, read and dequeue a word, then unlock and process the word.

Comment: Although your answer is good but it does not server the purpose of the user. User wants to call threads in batches, i.e same threads need to be start again.