# Do I need to terminate a started thread before starting another thread?

Tags: python, multithreading, tkinter

I have a button which calls a function. This function is called using a thread. If I click the button more than once I get an error: **RuntimeError: threads can only be started once**. I got the solution on SO (create a new thread). But if I create a new thread every time that button is clicked, what happens to the previous thread. **Should I worry about the previous threads?**

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import threading

root = tk.Tk()

#creating new thread on click
def start_rename():
    new_thread = threading.Thread(target= bulk_rename)
    new_thread.start()

def bulk_rename():
    print("renaming...")

rename_button = ttk.Button(root, text="Bulk Rename", command=start_rename)
rename_button.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/36937667/1025391

Comment: @moooeeeep Yes, but only related. There are multiple questions related to this post but they are solutions to the RuntimeError. I already have the solution.

Comment: If it's as simple as printing something, then no I don't think so. However if it gets complex and threads get stuck in infinite loops or get deadlocked, then it might be worth notifying or logging something when you suspect something funny is afoot. You could just have a list of all started threads and check them now and again to make sure the list doesn't get too huge, and clean up the list as threads are done.

Comment: @avm Please consider to close (or self-answer) this question then.

Comment: @moooeeeep No. I meant I already have the solution to RuntimeError but thats not what I am asking here.

Comment: @avm. It worked for me. I clicked button many times. No errors.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a different way to say the same things:

1. A [*mutex*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lock_(computer_science)) (a.k.a., a "lock", or a "binary semaphore") is an object with two methods; `lock()` and `unlock()`, or `acquire()` and `release()`, or `decrement()` and `increment()`, (or `P()` and `V()` in really old programs.) The `lock()` method does not return until the calling thread "owns"
   the mutex, and a subsequent call to the `unlock()` method from the
   same thread will relinquish ownership.
2. No two threads will be allowed to own the same mutex at the same time. If two or more threads simultaneously try to lock a mutex, one will immediately "win" ownership, and the others will wait for it to be unlocked again.
3. Assuming each of the competing threads eventually unlocks the mutex, then all of them eventually will be allowed to own the mutex, but only one-by-one. The `lock()` function cannot fail. The only thing it can do is wait for the mutex to become available, and then take ownership. If some thread in a buggy program keeps ownership of some mutex forever, then a subsequent attempt by some other thread to `lock()` that same mutex will wait forever.

> We sometimes call the part of the program that comes between a `lock()` call and the subsequent `unlock()` call a [*critical section*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Critical_section).

4. We can use a mutex as an [*advisory lock*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lock_(computer_science)).

> Imagine a program with three variables, A, B, and C, that are shared by several threads. The program has an important rule: A+B+C must always equal zero. Computer scientists call a rule like that an [*invariant*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invariant_(mathematics)#Invariants_in_computer_science)—it's a statement about the program that always is true.

> But, what happens if one thread needs to perform some operation, `mut()`, that changes the values of A, B, and C? It cannot change all three variables simultaneously, so it must temporarily *break* the invariant. In that moment, some other thread could see the variables in that broken state, and the program could fail.

> We fix that problem by having every thread `lock()` the same advisory lock (i.e., the same mutex) before accessing A, B, or C. And we make sure that A+B+C=0 again before any thread `unlocks()` the mutex. If the thread calling `mut()` obeys this rule, then no other thread that also obeys the same rule will ever see A, B, and C in the "broken" state.

> If none of the threads in the program ever accesses A, or B, or C without owning the mutex, then we can say that we have effectively made `mut()` an [*atomic operation*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linearizability#High-level_atomic_operations).

5. You actually should lock a mutex when accessing shared variables regardless of any invariant—do it even if accessing just a single, primitive flag or integer—because using mutexes on a multi-CPU machine enables the different CPUs to see a [*consistent view of memory*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consistency_model). In modern systems, access to the same variable by more than one thread with no locking can lead to [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).
6. A program with more than one invariant may use more than one mutex object to protect them: One mutex for each. But, programmers are strongly advised to learn about [*deadlock*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deadlock) before writing any program in which a single thread locks more than one mutex at the same time.

> "Deadlock" is the answer to a whole other question, but TLDR, it's what happens when Thread1 owns mutexA, and it's waiting to acquire mutexB; while at the same time, Thread2 owns mutexB, and is waiting to acquire mutexA. It's a thing that actually happens sometimes in real, commercial software, that was written by smart programmers. Usually it's because there were a *lot* of smart programmers, who weren't always talking to each other.